# problems installing 3.5.1 ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Have problems installing 3.5.1 ActionBarSherlock

I use JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-3.5.1-0-gc359e93 but in Eclipse have more(>100) errors.

Here you can view my steps..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=0XeKh_8zuGE

need help..

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the latest version of `ActionBarSherlock`?

Comment: some part of my code do not work for android:targetSdkVersion="14" 
and 
above.. 
Now I want to release app for targetSdkVersion="13" and below 
And then find solutions for resolve issues for 14 sdk 
Is it possible to use latest version of Sherlock 4.02 in project where 
android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="8"?

Comment: Android is backwards compatible, your code should work for version 14 or 15. Anyway, check Jake Wharton answer, he is the person who maintains `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I work with graphics and behavior for API 13 and 14 or 15 have little difference (
Now I'm trying to find solution

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock 3.5.x requires these things:

1. Compile both the library and your project with Android 3.2
2. Use Java 1.6 (6) compliance for compilation. In Eclipse this can be found under the "Java Compiler" settings of your project.
3. Specify a `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest of API level 11 or higher.

However, you should upgrade to [the latest ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) as version 3.x is no longer supported.

Comment: Thank, Jake!
some part of my code do not work correctly for android:targetSdkVersion="14" and above.. Now I want to release app for targetSdkVersion="13" and below.
And then find solutions for resolve issues for 14 sdk.

Is it possible to use latest version of Sherlock 4.02 in project where android:targetSdkVersion="13" android:minSdkVersion="8"?

Comment: Yes. Target SDK can be anywhere from 11 and up.